# Ampersand changing into a question mark in Terminal

Tags: 11.04, command-line, keyboard-layout

I run a server through terminal, and whenever a command with an '&' in it pops up, terminal sees it as a question mark. And when I try to save a configuration with an & in it it will eventually turn into a question mark as well. Any help with this annoying issue would be appreciated.

Edit: I am on Ubuntu 11.04 Btw.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something is wrong with the server's keyboard layout. You could try changing it. Other than that I'm not sure what to do.

Russian and moldovian keyboard layouts have a question mark <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd> (see [Wikipedia page about cyrillic keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Cyrillic)):

[image: From Wikipedia: russian keyboard]